# Rename duplicated column values group by another column

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, rename, data-manipulation

I have a dataset in which the same id appears in different groups:

```
df <- read.table(text='id   group  
 1         A 
 2         A 
 2         A 
 1         B 
 1         B 
 2         B
 2         C
 2         C 
 1         C 
 2         D         
 1         D
 1         D', header=TRUE)
```

I want to rename the duplicated values under column `id` that are grouped by another column `group`. The expected output is:

```
   id  group
    1     A
    2     A
    2     A
    1_2   B
    1_2   B
    2_2   B
    2_3   C
    2_3   C
    1_3   C
    2_4   D
    1_4   D
    1_4   D
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach using [`rleid()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.8/topics/rleid) to generate a run-length id for each unique `id` and `group` combination. We can then just `paste()` that number to the existing `id`, where it is `>1`.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, id_num := rleid(group), id][
    ,
    id := fifelse(
        id_num == 1,
        as.character(id),
        paste(id, id_num, sep = "_")
    )
][, `:=`(id_num = NULL)]

print(df)

#         id  group
#     <char> <char>
#  1:      1      A
#  2:      2      A
#  3:      2      A
#  4:    1_2      B
#  5:    1_2      B
#  6:    2_2      B
#  7:    2_3      C
#  8:    2_3      C
#  9:    1_3      C
# 10:    2_4      D
# 11:    1_4      D
# 12:    1_4      D
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See the `tidyverse` version below

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SamR's `data.table` answer. I was able to convert his/her code to a `tidyverse` version using Chatgpt:

```
df %>%
  mutate(id_num = data.table::rleid(group)) %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(id_num == 1, as.character(id), paste(id, id_num, sep = "_"))) %>%
  select(-id_num)
```

Comment: why do you need `data.table::rleid` in tidyverse? just use `dplyr::consecutive_id`